# OpenCL read_imagef precision

Tags: opencl, interpolation

I am trying to enlarge image 254x times. read_imagef return result that is not linear but staircase - I observe jump every 15 point. What is the precision of sampler.

Input is 9 values, output is 2304 values.

Excerpt from output:

```
x   read_imagef
120 120
121 120.9375
122 121.875
123 122.8125
124 123.75
125 124.6875
126 125.625
127 126.5625
128 128.4375
129 129.375
130 130.3125
131 131.25
132 132.1875
133 133.125
134 134.0625
135 135
136 135.9375
137 136.875
138 137.8125
139 138.75
140 139.6875
141 140.625
142 141.5625
143 143.4375
144 144.375
145 145.3125
146 146.25
147 147.1875
148 148.125
149 149.0625
150 150
```

I expect read_imagef returns the value of x.

P.S. I have tried it on Mali GPU.

Comment: Are you using float coordinates normalized or unnormalized?

Comment: @kanna float unnormalized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precision of the interpolation is implementation (usually hardware) defined, usually at least 8-bit.

The numbers you gave actually look worse than I would expect: 121, 120.9375(?) 122 .. 127, 126.5625(?), 128.

Using the sampler for interpolation is ok for enlarging images where 8-bit precision is fine. For anything more detailed (like a height map), you should do the interpolation in OpenCL and not rely on the sampler.

You also may run out of bits (there's only 23 plus one implied) calculating the coordinates in floating point. A value like 2304 is using 11 (10 plus one implied) bits for the integer portion leaving only 13 for the fractional part.

Comment: Input: 0,288,576,864,1152,1440,1728,2016,2304. Output in my question is few interpolated values between the first two points.

Comment: I have realized that it is due to limited precision in hardare interpolation and implemented interpolation in OpenCL like you suggested. Also intead of interpolating raw coordinates I am interpolating deviation from the reference coordinate - that allows to have same precision for all range of coodinates.